# Inverse of a triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ upper triangular matrix with integer entries and all diagonal entries are $1$

> Prove / Disprove: $A^{-1}$ is not a power of $A$ unless $A$ is the identity matrix

I only know $A^{-1}$ exists and of course, it has all integer entries.

Any help?

Comment: Why must $A^{-1}$ have all integer entries? Was this (like the fact that diagonal entries are $1$) given as part of the problem? Are there any other "givens" that you've failed to mention (like the diagonal entries)?

Comment: yes , all diagonal entries are 1. See my post again, i have edit it!

Comment: I saw that. I was asking if there was anything *else* that you didn't mention. Also: how do you know that $A^{-1}$ has all integer entries?

Comment: $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{det A} adj A$ , $det A=1$ and $adjA$ has all integer entries

Comment: Right. (That wasn't so clear before you added the "diagonal = 1" constraint. :( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $A=I+N$ where $N$ is some nilpotent non-zero upper triangular matrix and suppose $A^{-1}=(I+N)^k$.

Then it should be $(I+N)^{k+1}=I$ and then with the use of of binomial formula $a_1N+a_2N^2+\dots+ a_{k+1}N^{k+1} =0 $

$N(a_1I+a_2N +\dots+ a_{k+1}N^ k)  =0$

but $B=a_1I+a_2N +\dots+ a_{k+1}N^ k$ is full rank matrix and $N$ in nonzero matrix so it is impossible to be $NB=0$.

So $N$ must be $0$.

Comment: Very nice!.....

Comment: @lhf Thank you, we have similar answers given almost at the same time :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: work out the $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ cases by hand (i.e., assume your matrix is 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and its inverse is 
$$
A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & c \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and see what you can conclude about $a$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*  It is enough to prove that $A^m=I$ implies $A=I$.
Write $A=I+N$ with $N$ nilpotent. Then $A^m$ is easy to compute using the binomial theorem. Argue that $A^m=I$ implies $N=0$ by considering the diagonals of $N$. For instance, the secondary diagonal of $A^m$ is $m$ times the secondary diagonal of $N$.